# Count duplicate values from a list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am parsing some data from a database. But I don't want to show duplicate data and want to count how many duplicate data are in a list of objects. I want to do it with React.js

Here is my parsing data

[image: parsing data]

I don't want that jobaer or web will come multiple times, I want it to show like this:

```
 jobaer : 3
 web: 2
```

I have made a function to do that, but it's not working.

```
 this.state = {
                clientReqList:[],
               }

getClientReqList = () => {
        axios.get( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/SalesLead/getAll', {})
            .then((response) => {
                 console.log("response",response.data.data);
                this.setState({ clientReqList: response.data.data  });
            }).catch((error)=>{  console.log("error",error); this.setState({ clientReqList: []  });   });
    };

    count() {
            var array_elements= this.state.clientReqList;
            document.write(array_elements)
            array_elements.sort();

            var current = null;
            var cnt = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++) {
                if (array_elements[i] != current) {
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
                    }
                    current = array_elements[i];
                    cnt = 1;
                } else {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            if (cnt > 0) {
                document.write(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times');
            }


        }
```

Result shows:

```
[object Object] comes --> 1 times
[object Object] comes --> 1 times
```

Could anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator is the simplest way to achieve that.

There you can find a short example of that:
https://jsbin.com/gapeqewubo/edit?js,console,output

```
const results = {
 jobaer: 3,
 web: 2,
 anotherone: 4,
 web: 2,
 jobaer: 3
}

const uniqueResults = {
  ...results
}
```

**Interesting articles about this:**

https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

Be aware of rest operator which looks exact the same as the spread operator, the only
difference is that the rest operator is used in method parameters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters